# Detecting window onblur() event in Firefox, IE and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cross-browser, dom-events

I currently have the code below:

```
if (document.onfocusin !== undefined) {
    var onfocusin = true; 
}  
else{   
    var onfocusin = false; 
}

if (onfocusin === true)
{   
    document.onfocusout = ad_blur; //ad_blur is a function I defined 
                                   //when window.onblur() fires
}  else{
    window.onblur = ad_blur; 

}
```

Code works fine in IE 8 and Chrome 17 but not in Firefox 8, I also found some other code but the compatibility doesn't meet my need. So the question is : is there a way to determine `window.onblur()` event in IE, Firefox and Chrome?

More specifically, I want to handle the event when a new window (or tab) is open.

Comment: jQuery is really great at solving these compatability problems for you so that you can focus on the bigger picture. Unless there is some very compelling, good reason not to do so, you may want to look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as jmort253 mentioned, jQuery is really good at this, here is the code that works in almost every current browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).blur(function() {
        ad_blur();  //here is what you wanna do when blur fires
    });
});
```